# Magento:- Fatal error: Call to a member function isAllowedGuestCheckout() on a non-object

Tags: magento

I was trying to make a new web site but when I am tryin to check placing order thing 
I tried to make a new account as a customer so I am getting this error

> Fatal error: Call to a member function isAllowedGuestCheckout() on a non-object in /home/xxx.com/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/persistent/customer/form/register.phtml on line 30

Is there any solution?

Comment: Can you post some code please, and explain what it is you are trying to achieve?

Comment: please chk here http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/288861/